# How to save/download an image from my custom phtml page in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, custom, image, download

```
<div class='image_gallery_outer'>
<?php foreach($image_array as $arr){
$image = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."appimages/".trim($arr['newFileName']);
?>

<div class='image_gallery'>
    <img src="<?php echo  $image ?>"/>
    <span>
        <a href="<?php echo  $image ?>" download>
            <button class="download_img"><img style="display:none;" src="<?php echo  $image ?>"/>Download</button>
        </a>
    </span></div>   <?php }?>
</div>
```

Used above code, but its not working on safari & IE

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the JS implementation, something like:

```
// IE10+ : (has Blob, but not a[download] or URL)
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
      return navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
}
```

That should do the trick in IE according to this library https://github.com/rndme/download/blob/master/download.js#L143

Or you can follow this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473932/browser-html-force-download-of-image-from-src-dataimage-jpegbase64

That might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller that will send back the image with the proper HTTP headers.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MyFileName.ext
```